# Process Mining algorithm

Tags: process, bigdata, data-mining, mining

If I have windows usage data table like

StartTime | EndTime | Window | Value

that records a history of windows usage - how can we mine this data to get some repetitive patters, e.g. wnd1->wnd2->wnd3 (set of records running consistently, set of records in different patterns may vary.. ) ?

What algorithm is better to use for this? Are there any implementations for Excel, Python and Delphi?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your data is not suitable for process mining. In process mining, we need a mandatory field that is "case-Id". Without this info, it is almost impossible to benefit most process mining techniques.

It would be great if you can provide case-Id or use Sequence mining techniques instead.